# Linq GroupBy Max and add column

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, max

I need to display the last activity from a tracking log and groupby the ClientId and the Last Activity date. I have the code working fine.

I now need to add another column to the results which is the "Memo" field.

The end query will be Last Tracking Date by ClientId and the 'Memo' field from that row.

Working Code (without Memo field)

```
var q =(
from t in Trackings
group t by t.ClientID into g
select new {ClientID = g.Key, Date = g.Max(x=>x.TrackDate)} 
).ToList();
```

Results:

```
46, 10/29/2015 12:09:42 PM 
69, 11/1/2015 5:44:47 AM 
29, 11/6/2015 12:55:21 PM
```

Desired Results

```
46, 10/29/2015 12:09:42 PM, User Login 
69, 11/1/2015 5:44:47 AM, Update Account
29, 11/6/2015 12:55:21 PM, User Login
```

How can I add another column AFTER the GroupBy and MAX select has completed and get the MEMO for the ROW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most convenient way for this kind of queries is to sort by the date in descending order and take the first record:

```
var q =(from t in Trackings
        group t by t.ClientID into g
        let lastTracking = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.TrackDate).FirstOrDefault()
        select new 
        {
            ClientID = g.Key, 
            Date = lastTracking.TrackDate,
            Memo = lastTracking.Memo
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes you are correct +1. You can just warn OP for possibility of NRE which can happen because of `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: That's right, but I leave that to the OP. `Trackings` might be an `IQueryable` from a SQL backend, in which case null-checks wouldn't apply.

Comment: @RahulSingh NRE never happens on grouping with no additional filter. Normally one would use `First`, but from some unknown reason EF does not like it and requires `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Comment: @IvanStoev I didn't even think of that :) Of course the group is always populated. If there's no `ClientId`, there's no group.

Comment: @IvanStoev - I guess you got me wrong :) I was talking  abt the possibility of NRE at `lastTracking.Memo` not in grouping.

Comment: @RahulSingh I got that from the beginning :), but probably didn't express what I mean correctly (although Gert got that immediately). The point was that grouping result set for each key is never empty, thus `FirstOrDefault` never returns `null`, hence no NRE at `lastTracking` property access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
var q =(
from t in Trackings
group t by t.ClientID into g
select new {ClientID = g.Key, Date = g.Max(x=>x.TrackDate),MemoField=g.First().select(x=>x.MemoField)} 
).ToList();
```

Comment: Nope -- Resulted in ALL MEMO Fields .. not just the 1 for the row.

Comment: That will fetch the first item in each group.